# Scroll to position inside bootstrap panel

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a panel`(bootstrap)` with a lot of results from my database. when I click on 1 of the results, it will open a side window with details.

Sometimes I have the panel filled with `100+` rows, so when I scroll down and click on 1 of the href's, it will refresh and go back to top.

What I want: When I click on the href, it will scroll back to this href inside the panel.

What i've tried? a lot.....

What came close? get the scroll pos with `javascript` using this:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function (event) {
        var scroll = this.scrollY;
        console.log(scroll)
});
```

This only works with the main scrollbar. does not give the pos from my scrollbar inside the panel

Some pictures:

[image: First page, search]

[image: Second page, Details]

**A bit more info:** when I click on the href, i redirect to another page with the same panel & href list as the previous page.

This is a small and cropped part of the script:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <i class="fa-fw"></i>Job lijst voor resource id:
        <span style="float:right;">
                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="javascript:history.back()">
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left"  aria-hidden="true"></i> Terug
                    </a>
                </span>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body col-lg-12" style="overflow-y: auto; height: 700px">
        <div class="list-group">
          <?php
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            ?>
            <a href="blablablabla" class="list-group-item" style="background-color: #<?php echo $fontColor; ?>">
              <!-- background color to highlight the selected href -->
              <div style="text-align:left">
                <div class="row">
                  Some info from the database
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```